# mysql administrator

Tags: mysql

I have the MySQL administrator tool running on the same Windows machine as the MySQL server itself. When I try to logon to the server, I get the message:

[image: error msg]

The administrator tool starts, but some pages are blank except for the message "This section is only available when connected to localhost". However, in my case I am connected to localhost, i.e. the admin tool and the MySQL server are on the same machine.

[image: disabled page]

Any idea how I can get this tool to work?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix [here](http://www.mgwalk.com/Temp_Topic_View.php?ID=97)

Answer (score 0):

You might be connected *to* localhost, but for purposes of that error message you probably also need to be connected *via* localhost, i.e. it sounds like you're talking to your mysql server via the local machine's IP number or DNS name, and it wants you to talk to it via the name localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your mysql server is missing its configuration file. Restart Mysql server and check in the Application event log for Mysql complains.